# How to get geolocalisation , request from AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare

My problem is that I have an API Gateway in France, and this API Gateway calls our API which is proxied on CloudFlare .

On CloudFlare, I put a transformation rule that depends on the geolocation, the problem is that it always returns that the request comes from France because of the API Gateway in France, while I want the original source of the request, how to solve this?

Comment: How are you calling the API proxied on cloudflare? Via a lambda function?